# How long will it take to install and import data into CiviCRM?

Tags: database, joomla

I haven't used CiviCRM before and I was asked if I can install it on a Joomla-based web site. I also need to import about 3,000 records from 4 different MS Excel files. I'm hoping I can do this in 10-12 hours, but I haven't used CiviCRM before, and I'd like opinions from anyone who has experience with this. I know a precise figure isn't possible, but estimates or even rough figures are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

You need to save Excel file in CSV format. Importing depends on amount of data you have in your csv file for each record. Feel free to ask more questions on http://forum.civicrm.org

Comment: +1 for the forum recommendation, where Kurund's been very helpful to me.